# How to disable font scaling in RN for Android?

Tags: android, react-native

Simply using `allowFontScaling={false}` fixes this on iOS, but I'm unsure how to set this on Android.

Also, for anyone that's not familiar with RN and is coming here from the Android tag, I don't think I can easily change from to `dp` font scaling or whatever, so is there a way I can do it globally in my app somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered setting the font value based on screen density? In android text size is set with "sp" indicating that the font should scale to appear to be the same physical size on screens with higher pixel density. If you defined a "dimen" attribute for the text size in question, then created different "dimens.xml" files for each screen density (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, and xxxhdpi) and determined what the font size should be for each screen density, it sounds like that should accomplish what you're looking for

Comment: @JaceJMcPherson
I'm not sure i understand. could you explain where in RN can you set a text size with 'sp' on a Text element?

Comment: Am also facing the same issue.Kindly tell me if you got the solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please Update ManiApplication.java file

```
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
```

After `super.onCreate();` method put `adjustFontScale(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getConfiguration());`

Like follow

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    adjustFontScale(getApplicationContext(),getResources().getConfiguration());
}
```

And at the end add the following function

```
public void adjustFontScale(Context context, Configuration configuration) {
    if (configuration.fontScale != 1) {
        configuration.fontScale = 1;
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
    }
}
```

Comment: We need a force-accept feature on SO in case OP bails like this.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko I didnt "bail".... he literally answered it over a year later where my question isn't even relevant anymore. I'll mark it as accepted just based on the fact it "seems" its correct, but I can't verify it, so I didn't mark it

Comment: @Tallboy Sorry, I didn't mean it in a bad way! Was just thinking about an accept-vote feature similar to close-vote.